# Building linq query that collect records by group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

scenario is simple actually but handling it in linq require more exp than I have..
There is 3 table

```
Table1
ID Column
1   val1
2   val2
Table2
ID Column
1   val3
2   val4
Table3
ID Column
1   val5
2   val6
```

I need such a query that returns;

TableResult:

```
Row ID Column Type
1   1   val1  table1
2   2   val2  table1
3   1   val3  table2
4   2   val4  table2
5   1   val5  table3
6   2   val6  table3
```

Searched on net and started like below but cant figure how handle the tricks create "type", merge records etc..

```
  from t1 in table1 
    join t2 in table2 on t1.id equals t2.id
    join t3 in table3 on t1.id equals t3.id
    select new {...}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter mate. just use join twice.

Comment: But then values repeat itself, check it i edited post, i need merge the records join only repeat particular columns as count of records right ?

Comment: I can't see why you need a join. Concatenate the tables adding an extra "Type" column in each sub-query

Comment: but tables have diffirent column in origin join and arrange them with foreign key looks my solution here

Comment: You don't need joins, but `Select` + `Concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as what you did try Distinct at the end. query syntax would be :

```
var List = (from t1 in dbContext.table1
                  join t2 in dbContext.table2 on t1.ID equals t2.ID
                  join t3 in dbContext.table3 on t1.ID equals t3.ID
                  select new
                  {
                   //t1.DesiredColumnName,
                   //t2.DesiredColumnName,
                   //t3.DesiredColumnName,
                   //so on
                  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: bro tell me how to get these "values" data in column.. this is only return  empty list. I want the output as i mention in post

Comment: @TyForHelpDude i don't know your field names or column names, so i just put a comment u can get the rest from here.

Comment: but how to add Type column here ?

Comment: @TyForHelpDude its easy return an alias as Type see my edit soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154219/discussion-between-ecko-and-tyforhelpdude).

Answer (score 2):

You've already accepted an answer, so I don't know if this is what you WANT, but it generates the output you specified in your post.

Because you have only used Id values of 1 and 2, it's unclear whether you actually want to perform a Join or just get the set of all rows into a single result.

Anyway:

```
struct TableStructure
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Column { get; set; }
}

var t1 = new List<TableStructure>() { new TableStructure { Id = 1, Column = "val1" }, new TableStructure { Id = 2, Column = "val2" } };
var t2 = new List<TableStructure>() { new TableStructure { Id = 1, Column = "val3" }, new TableStructure { Id = 2, Column = "val4" } };
var t3 = new List<TableStructure>() { new TableStructure { Id = 1, Column = "val5" }, new TableStructure { Id = 2, Column = "val6" } };

var result = ((from row1 in t1 select new { row1.Id, row1.Column, SourceTable = "table1" })
        .Union(from row2 in t2 select new { row2.Id, row2.Column, SourceTable = "table2" })
        .Union(from row3 in t3 select new { row3.Id, row3.Column, SourceTable = "table3" }))
        .AsEnumerable().Select((row, index) => new { RowNum = index + 1, row.Id, row.Column, row.SourceTable });

result.ToList().ForEach(row => Console.WriteLine($"{row.RowNum}, {row.Id}, {row.Column}, {row.SourceTable}"));
```

output:

```
1, 1, val1, table1
2, 2, val2, table1
3, 1, val3, table2
4, 2, val4, table2
5, 1, val5, table3
6, 2, val6, table3
```

Comment: yes I solved my problem but appreciated for your post :)